# How to show a Popup in Datepicker Bootstrap when click on day

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

How do I do show a pop-up in a calendar when I click on a day of the month.

For example, I'd like to see what events or festivals are gonna be on that day I just clicked. I have the code, which is normal on every bootstrap case.

Thank you, and best regards.

Comment: if you have a question ask it as new one , dont update the old one . -1 for updatingthe old question . revert the question then i'll revert my vote

Comment: Don't do that, @Rodolfo. The system asked you to wait a week to ask a new question, and perhaps spend that time improving your previous questions - vandalizing them disrespects the work that folks have put into answering your queries, and is just gonna prolong the wait.